# Usermanager find async error

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-identity

i'm trying to authenticate on a .net api with Oauth token and i get the following error when i'm accessing the /auth route:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred.
>   The specified LocalDB instance does not exist.

All day long i tried to fix this but with no success. I'll be glad if i get some help.

So, this is the code where i get the error:

```
   var allowedOrigin = "*";

        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { allowedOrigin });

        var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        AspnetUserService service = new AspnetUserService();


        ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password); <---- here, when i send via Postman, i'll wait ~2 minutes to get a response. When the response arrived, this above error appears.
```

What is weird is that i tried to make a new registration on DB with identity and it worked. I tried to get some values from DB, worked too.

I run a SQL server locally, these are my two connection strings:

```
<add name="AuthContext" connectionString="Server=localhost;Initial Catalog=SeeMe2;User ID=SeeMe2;Password=password;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="SeeMe2Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Context.SeeMe.csdl|res://*/Context.SeeMe.ssdl|res://*/Context.SeeMe.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=localhost;initial catalog=SeeMe2;persist security info=True;user id=SeeMe2;password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I tried to debug the code, all the variables seem to have the right values. 
Any suggestions? Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a trouble with your SQL connectin string.

Your connection string is:

```
<add name="AuthContext" connectionString="localhost;Initial Catalog=SeeMe2;User ID=SeeMe2;Password=password;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

There you have not Server and Database attribute.

The correct connection string is:

```
<add name="AuthContext" connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=SeeMe2;User ID=SeeMe2;Password=password;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

More information about connection string is [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/).

Also check your `SeeMe2Entities` connection string.

As I can see it has incorrect values on connection section (you have missed Server and Database also).

Answer (score 0):

At the AuthContext connection string `Server` attribute missing. it should be like this.

```
<add name="AuthContext" connectionString="Server=localhost;Initial Catalog=SeeMe2;User ID=SeeMe2;Password=password;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: do you have any SQL instance name or using default instance?

Comment: This is what i found in Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances

:ProjectsV13;
:MSSQLLocalDB;

Comment: it looks like you have also an instance name. if have, change `localhost ` to `localhost\instance_name`

Comment: so i tried with \ MSSQLLocalDB , not working. I tried with my ip, not working. any other ideas?